# Float in two div

Tags: css, forms, html, css-float, margin

HTML

```
<div id="form">
    <img class="photo" src="---" /> 
    [...]
</div>
```

CSS

```
.photo{
    float: left;
}
#form {        
    float: right;
    padding: 35px;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}
```

Problem is that the image is attached to the div. I tryed to put margin but don't work.
Some solution?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you want as an end result?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nQFWL/ I want that the line can move left

Comment: is it what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/xDAYa/

Comment: Yes! But if I have an input and select 'text-align' don't work, what can I use to move them right?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bringing in an outside image, draw a left border on your container (div#form) using

```
border-left: 1px solid black;
```